# Ruby: Use Date.Parse to determine if date is erroneous

Tags: ruby, function, if-statement, automated-tests

I have test file that has a list of tests to run on my other file which demand an assert for an erroneous date

```
require "minitest/autorun"
require "./simple_date"

describe SimpleDate do
  it "works as expected" do
    assert_raises { SimpleDate.new(1969, 12, 31) }
    assert_raises { SimpleDate.new(2016, 1, 32) }
    assert_raises { SimpleDate.new(2016, 2, 30) }
    assert_raises { SimpleDate.new(2016, 3, 32) }
    assert_raises { SimpleDate.new(2016, 4, 31) }
    # ... there are more this is just a sample
  end
```

This part of my other file works:

```
require 'date'

class SimpleDate
  attr_reader :year, :month, :day
  def initialize(year, month, day) 
    if !year.between?(1970, 2020)
      raise 'Error: Year not betwen 1970 and 2020'
    elsif !month.between(1, 12)
      raise 'Error: Month not between 1 and 12'
    elsif !day.between?(1, 31)
      raise 'Error: Day not between 1 and 31'
    end
```

This part of my other file does not work.

```
begin
  Date.parse(year, month, day)
rescue
  raise 'Date Format Error'
end
```

Can you please help me better format my second part so that it will pass the tests?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `Date#parse` to check the input, use it:

```
class SimpleDate
  MESSAGE = 'Date Format Error'
  def initialize(year, month, day)
    # explicitly reject before unix epoch
    raise MESSAGE if !year.between(1970, 2020)
    begin
      Date.parse "#{year}/#{month}/#{day}"
    rescue ArgumentError
      raise MESSAGE
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you want to use `Date` to check for a valid date, use `Date.valid_date?(y, m, d)` ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, [Date::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) is not very discrimintating: `Date.parse("1111")
 => #<Date: 2017-11-11 ((2458069j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`. @Stefan, is `Date#valid` from Rails?

Comment: @CarySwoveland from stdlib: [`Date::valid_date?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-valid_date-3F)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mudasowba, I had to modify your code a little bit to this:

```
class SimpleDate
  MESSAGE = 'Date Format Error'

  def initialize(year, month, day) 
    raise MESSAGE if !year.between?(1970, 2020)
    begin
      Date.parse "#{year}/#{month}/#{day}"
    rescue ArgumentError
      raise MESSAGE
    end
  end
end
```

You saved me a lot of time and improved my understanding.  Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my answer, please remove this one since it contradits rules of SO.